# Get all the rows for the most recent 3 groups

Tags: mysql, sql

I googled a bit and looked on SO but I didn't find anything that helped me.

I have a working MySQL query that selects some columns (accross three tables, with two JOIN statements) and I am looking to do something extra on the result set.

I would like to SELECT all rows from the 3 most recent groups. (I can only assume I have to use a GROUP BY on that column) I'm having a hard time explaining this clearly so I'll use an example:

```
id | group
--------------
1  | 1
2  | 2
3  | 2
4  | 2
5  | 3
6  | 3
7  | 4
8  | 4
```

Of course, I dumbed it down a lot for the sake of simplicity (and my current query doesn't include an id column).

Right now my ideal query would return, in order (that's the id field):

8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2

If I were to add the following 9th element:

```
id | group
--------------
9  | 5
```

My ideal query would then return, in order:

9, 8, 7, 6, 5

Because these are all the rows from the most 3 recent groups. Also, when two rows have the same group (and are still in the results set), I would like to ORDER them BY another field (which I have not included in my dumbed down example).

In my search I only found how to do actions on elements of GROUPS (MAX of each, AVG of group elements, etc.) and not GROUPS themselves (first 3 groups ordered by a field).

Thank you in advance for your help!

Edit: Here is what my real query looks like.

```
SELECT t1.f1, t1.f2, t2.f1, t2.f2, t2.f3, t3.f1, t3.f2, t3.f3, t3.f4
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.f1=t1.f3
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.f1=t3.f5
WHERE t1.f4='some_constant' AND t2.f4='some_other_constant'
ORDER BY t1.f2 DESC
```

Comment: How do you identify "most recent" groups?

Comment: In this case, it would be "equivalent" to 'ORDER BY group DESC LIMIT 3' if that query was applied on groups themselves.

Comment: -1 I can't do it without the query you already have, there's just not enough info, please paste the query you have in the question.

Comment: @Johan I have edited my post with something that resembles my query.

Comment: ok, but which field represents `group`? and is it an aggregate field, or just a normal field. You are making us run around in circles :-(

Comment: @Mathieu - the left joins make it difficult, but i have updated my answer with a query which should work.

Comment: @Johan The field which represents group is t2.f3. Not sure I know exactly the difference between an aggregate and a normal field, but that field is only present in the table t2. Sorry if my example lacked clarity.

@JIStone Thank you, I will give it a shot right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `table`.* FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT `group`
FROM `table`
ORDER BY `group` DESC LIMIT 3) t1
INNER JOIN `table` ON `table`.`group` = t1.`group`
```

the subquery should return the three groups with the largest value, the `INNER JOIN` will ensure no rows are included which do not have these group values.

---

assuming t1.f2 is your group column:

```
SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i
FROM
(
  SELECT t1.f1 as a, t1.f2 as b, t2.f1 as c, t2.f2 as d, t2.f3 as e, t3.f1 as f, t3.f2 as g, t3.f3 as h, t3.f4 as i
  FROM t1 
  LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.f1=t1.f3
  LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.f1=t3.f5
  WHERE t1.f4='some_constant' AND t2.f4='some_other_constant'
  ORDER BY t1.f2 DESC
) first_table
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT DISTINCT `f2`
  FROM `t1`
  ORDER BY `f2` DESC LIMIT 3
) second_table
ON first_table.b = second_table.f2
```

Note that this may be very inefficient depending on your table structure, but is the best I can do without more information.

Comment: @JIstone you do know that `group` and `table` are reserved words?

Comment: @Johan - yes I was, but I figured we were talking hypotheticals so I didn't bother. Added now.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for my needs. However, I'm curious about how it would be done if I wanted the most 3 recent groups from the query result and not the most recent groups from the table f2.

Comment: @Mathieu - Not sure your meaning, but if you are concerned about getting groups that do not match your constraints, you can add the constraints into the second subquery . . . .

Comment: @JIStone No, I meant that since I use a LEFT JOIN statement for the table where my "group" column is, the 3 most recent groups in my big query results aren't necessarily the 3 same as the ones in that column alone. So from what you're saying, I should basically add the bulk of my first query into the subquery? (That means the JOIN statements too)

Comment: @Mathieu - seems like that might be the best solution - seems inefficient, but I can't see a better way. In some cases two separate queries are actually better than one, but those cases are rare. Something to conciser if this becomes a bottleneck in the future, probably.

Answer (score 0):

how about this way... (i use groupId instead of 'group'

```
[QUERY] => something like (SELECT id, groupId from tables.....) (your query with 2 joins).

-- with this query you have the last thre groups.
[QUERY2] => SELECT distinct(groupId) as groupId FROM ([QUERY]) ORDER BY groupId DESC LIMIT 0,3
```

and finally you will have:

```
SELECT id, groupId from tables----...... WHERE groupId in ([QUERY2]) order by groupId DESC, id DESC
```

Comment: So technically my original query will basically end up twice in this new one? Because it's a pretty long one!